# Ошибка сервера PHP Notice: phpDoc 4 piece(s) @param description expected in UTF8::diactrical_remove(), 0 given

Tags: php, битрикс

На сайте не сохраняются товары. Добавляются, но если потом отредактировать, то не сохраняются изменения.
В чем ошибка и как исправить?

Лог:

> [30-May-2016 08:06:58 Europe/Moscow] PHP Notice:  phpDoc 4 piece(s)
>   @param description expected in UTF8::diactrical_remove(), 0 given, 
>   called in
>   /home/a124341/web/site.ru/public_html/includes/Text_WordsParser/Text/WordsParser.php
>   on line 105  and defined in
>   /home/a124341/web/site.ru/public_html/includes/Text_WordsParser/UTF8.php
>   on line 864 in
>   /home/a124341/web/site.ru/public_html/includes/Text_WordsParser/ReflectionTypeHint.php
>   on line 31

Comment: У вас TorrentPier? Если да, ему версия php 5.3 нужна. Если нет, укажите, что у вас CMS. Какая версия. Дайте больше подробностей.

Comment: Не TorrentPier, версия PHP 5.4, 1С-Битрикс с последними обновлениями

Comment: А используется стандартное решение или свой код для товаров? Ошибка говорит о том, что внутри функции `diactrical_remove` ожидается 4 переданных параметра (1 обязательный), а передано в нее 0. В частности не передана сама строка, из которой нужно удалить диакритические знаки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено, проблема была в том, что при добавление товара копировался html код со спецсимволами, удаление которых решило проблему.